# Complicated sorting with tabs in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following JSON object:

```
      $scope.projects = [
  {
    "_id": "58ab1cb6edf5430e9014e2bc",
    "name": "Project 1",
    "issues": [
      {
        "status": 0,
        "name": "Hart Cummings"
      },
      {
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Kinney Leach"
      },
      {
        "status": 2,
        "name": "Blake Mclaughlin"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "_id": "58ab1cb6d87456482e0eec4a",
    "name": "Project 2",
    "issues": [
      {
        "status": 0,
        "name": "Vargas Gordon"
      },
      {
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Bobbie Church"
      },
      {
        "status": 2,
        "name": "Pennington Fry"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "_id": "58ab1cb6d87456482e0eec4a",
    "name": "Project 3",
    "issues": [
      {
        "status": 0,
        "name": "WWWWW"
      },
      {
        "status": 1,
        "name": "SFSF"
      },
      {
        "status": 2,
        "name": "Pennington Fry"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I use `ng-repeat` to display this object in template:

```
    <div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="TodoListController">

<div ng-repeat="project in projects">
<br>
   <br>
 <div><b> {{project.name}}</b></div>

   <div class="tabs">
      <div style="display:inline" ng-click="sort(1, $index);">Active</div> |
      <div style="display:inline" ng-click="sort(0, $index);">Deactivated</div> 
   </div>

   _____________________________________
   <div ng-repeat="issue in project.issues | filter: (filterObject.index | filterObject.status)">
      <div>{{issue.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

So, as you can see I have two nested `ng-repeat`.

Issue is:

When I click on any tab and call method `sort()` I need to sort `issue in project.issues` by `status` field.

This is real sample that I want to reach.

https://jsfiddle.net/at6kw67g/

Problem is in this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="issue in project.issues | filter:filterObject.index : {status : filterObject.status}">
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/67a5gdtx/7/

Comment: I updated question and added sample my attemps

Comment: Your "JSON object" code is not valid JS code. Why don't you just 1. pass the project to sort to your sort() function; 2. Use The standard sort() method of JS arrays to sort the issues of the project?

Comment: I clear question and added more real sample

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/XK18lubQ2dO2Uercz6Cx?p=preview

Comment: Look again, now problem is in: `filter: (filterObject.index | filterObject.status)`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/at6kw67g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the links should sort the issues of a specific project, you should pass the project as argument to your sort() function.

And JavaScript arrays have a sort() method, so just use it.

Since one link should sort issues in ascanding order, and the other one in descending order, you should also pass this information to your sort() function.

So it boils down to

```
  $scope.sortIssuesByStatus = function(project, descending) {
    project.issues.sort(function(issue1, issue2) {
      var result = issue1.status - issue2.status;
      if (descending) {
        result = -result;
      }
      return result;
    });
  }
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects">
   <div class="tabs">
      <button ng-click="sortIssuesByStatus(project, true)">Active</button> 
      <button ng-click="sortIssuesByStatus(project, false)">Deactivated</button> 
   </div>
   <div ng-repeat="issue in project.issues">
      <div>{{issue.name}} - {{ issue.status }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's [a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XK18lubQ2dO2Uercz6Cx?p=preview) implementing it.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but could you see my sample, it is more easy to understand and finish

Comment: Problem is in this part: `<div ng-repeat="issue in project.issues | filter:filterObject.index : {status : filterObject.status}">`

Comment: Why don't you read my answer? It does what you're asking: "When I click on any tab and call method sort() I need to sort issue in project.issues by status field". Your JSFiddle example is broken.

Comment: Look here, it works: `https://jsfiddle.net/at6kw67g/1/` I tested this on local machine

Comment: No it doesn't. Let's assume it works anyway. What's the point of asking a question if you have a working solution already. Let's assume it doesn't work: why don't you read my answer, which does work, at least according to my understanding of your question. And why not ask for clarifications, or explain what you really want, if my understanding is not correct?

Comment: I am reading your answer, but I want to finish my sample: https://jsfiddle.net/at6kw67g/2/

Comment: In HTML section you can copy/past my code to local machine and check it: https://jsfiddle.net/at6kw67g/3/

Comment: Just to be crystal clear. You asked a question. I provided an answer. You didn't even consider it although it works absolutely fine, and comes with a link to a plunkr showing it in action. I won't continue to bother with your requests, since you don't care about anything I might answer anyway.

Comment: No, you gave me right answer, I got it. It works accoding my question!

Comment: Man, I checked your post. It does not work correct, when  I click tab "active" I need to show only rows with status = 1 and hide others

Comment: Ask another question requesting this new behavior. Your question literally asks: "I need to sort issue in project.issues by status field". You're using the term "sort" everywhere. But the principle is basically the same. Add a `filteredIssues` array to each project. When asked to **filter** the issues, then replace this filtered array. Display this filtered array in the HTML. JavaScript arrays have a filter() method.